# React Validation Max Range Using Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to make a validation using React and Formik. I wanted to achieve that the max digit is only 2 and the max range should be only to 12.

```
expiryMonth: yup.string().required('Select month').max(2, 'Invalid month format (Example: 06)'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
yup.string()
  .required("Select month")
  .min(2, "Invalid month format (Example: 06)")
  .max(2, "Invalid month format (Example: 06)")
  .matches(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$/, "Month must be greater than 0 and can't be exceeded 12");
```

Comment: I think it's ok, please have a look into [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shahnawazhossan-yup-lhjyp) and check.

Comment: The regex means, if the first position is 0 then it can take 1-9 on the second position or if the first position is 1, then it can take 0,1,2 on second position only. I think this condition is ok in your case. I hope it will help.

Comment: Your textfield is declared as `number` type, change it from `number` to `string`. It will work.

Comment: It's because you've given the input as a number and checked as a string.

Comment: This regex means, if the first position is 0 then it can take 1-9 on the second position or if the first position is 1, then it can take 0,1,2 on second position only. So in your case, there are only these two options can occur.

Comment: Ok, let me check.